# CSS is applied from the last object in CSS file instead of closest parent

Tags: css

I am building a web site that is basically made out of sections + rows + columns and to each element you can apply a color scheme.

If the color scheme is applied to the section, all the rows and columns within it will have the same color scheme, however, sometimes I want to add a color scheme to a single column to differentiate it, but in some cases the parent section color scheme css is placed AFTER the color scheme css for the column (in the css file), and then it applies the colors for the section instead of the columns.

Here is the code (simplified for the sake of example).

I could get around it in specific cases, using !important, but I am looking for a global solution.

CSS:

```
     /* Grey */
     .color-scheme-grey button {
         background-color: #666666;
         color: #ffffff;
     }    

     /* Blue */
     .color-scheme-blue button {
         background-color: blue;
         color: #ffffff;
     }
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="section color-scheme-blue">
         <div class="row">
             <div class="column color-scheme-grey">
                 <button>I am blue, but I wish I was grey!</button>
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: just make some special classes for what you need and attach to the specific element

Comment: Why is it downvoted? The question was obviously good enough to render good answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behaviour as a direct result of Cascade Precedence.

If two rules carry the same **weight** or *specificity* the rule declared *last* always wins and *over-qualifies* the other.

**Use more *Specificity***

Consider declaring another *element* or *class* selector in the range of the *contextual selectors* already specified.

**Example:**

Added element selector (`div`) for more specificity...

```
div.color-scheme-grey button { ... }
```

Added a class selector (`.section`) for more specificity...

```
.section .color-scheme-grey button { ... }
```

**Code Snippet Demonstrations:**

**1. Additional Class Selector:**

```css
/* Grey */

.section .color-scheme-grey button {
  background-color: #666666;
  color: #ffffff;
}


/* Blue */

.color-scheme-blue button {
  background-color: blue;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="section color-scheme-blue">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column color-scheme-grey">
      <button>I am blue, but I wish I was grey!</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**2. Additional Element Selector:**

```css
/* Grey */

div.color-scheme-grey button {
  background-color: #666666;
  color: #ffffff;
}


/* Blue */

.color-scheme-blue button {
  background-color: blue;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="section color-scheme-blue">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column color-scheme-grey">
      <button>I am blue, but I wish I was grey!</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**For Further Information regarding CSS Specificity:**

1. [Specificity - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)
2. [Specifics on CSS Specificity | CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

Comment: Thanks! This is what I need to do. I created a colors-section.css (".section.color-scheme-grey button") followed by colors-row.css (".row.color-scheme-grey button") and colors-column.css (".column.color-scheme-grey button"). This seems to me to be the only way to find a global solution. This is the same solution that @Andy G suggests, but I'll mark this one as correct since it includes an example.

Answer (score 0):

Apply your styles from the parent like below.

```
.section .color-scheme-grey button {
     background-color: #666666;
     color: #ffffff;
 }
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/v5fv3smu/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You could increase the specificity of the rules to counteract the order of the files:

```
 /* Grey */
 .color-scheme-grey button {
     background-color: #666666;
     color: #ffffff;
 }    

 /* Blue */
 .color-scheme-blue button {
     background-color: blue;
     color: #ffffff;
 }    

 .color-scheme-blue .color-scheme-grey button {
    background-color: #666666;
 }
```

You need to be careful with this, though, as it can very quickly get out of hand with all the combinations!

Better would be to organise a set of formatting that applies to rows/sections and, separately, columns, and organise them appropriately in a file (sections first).

Comment: Thanks! This is what I need to do. I created a colors-section.css (".section.color-scheme-grey button") followed by colors-row.css (".row.color-scheme-grey button") and colors-column.css (".column.color-scheme-grey button"). This seems to me to be the only way to find a global solution.